# sizeof(function_name)

Tags: c, function, sizeof

I tried `sizeof(printf)` , `sizeof(foobar)` etc. where foobar is a user defined function. It returns 1 without any warning or error. Why 1?

Comment: what'd be the size of a function? how many bytes the underlying cpu opcodes take? how much memory the function occupies? how long the string representing the function's name is? how much space it mallocs during operation?

Comment: see also, http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#index-void_002c-size-of-pointer-to-2454

Comment: I had expected it to be the size of a function pointer, which 1 most probably isn't.

Comment: @Hasturkun - Thanks a ton for that gcc manual link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The size of functions is not well defined in C, so the value is meaningless.